# Setting and Getting names from pixi Graphic

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, interactive, pixi.js

I believe I have dynamically named all my pixi Graphics via a for loop using name = however when I try to console log out that name on click I just get the last one no matter which graphic I press, I couldn’t see a simple way to inspect the list of graphics in my pixi canvas ?

The idea will be on either pointer down or pointer up I retrieve the name of the graphic to use else where ?

Any tips appreciated.
The main component code is here https://gitlab.adamprocter.co.uk/nn/nodenoggin/-/blob/fixConns/app/src/components/ConnectionsLayer.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a single PIXI.Graphics object to represent *all* your buttons, which is not going to work how you expect.  While you *can* draw multiple primitives into a Graphics object, they'll all be treated as part of the same logical object.  Meaning, when you set buttons.name = 'foo', that's setting the name of the single PIXI.Graphics object, *not* the name of the primitives you're drawing into it.

To fix this, change your code to have a single PIXI.Graphics object *per button*, and then your code will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks yes I have been trying this but I cannot workout how to dynamically create a separate graphic based on a loop I can’t create using . Or bracket syntax var buttton[x] = new PIXI.Graphics - which is driving me loopy. Any tips on how to create a dynamic set or an array to do this. Thanks

Comment: I'd create an object (aka hash) with a map from your button "id", whatever that is, to the graphics object that represents that button.  So: var buttonMap = {};  buttonMap['login'] = new PIXI.Graphics(); ... build button here ...